# SELECT specific rows sql query Java 8

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa, jdbc

I've to extract some specific data from Oracle DB. I'm using Java 8.
I have to consider 3 columns from a TABLE : flag | date_1 | date_2.
The *flag* can have values 1,2 or 3 (The *flag* values updates from 1->2->3 over a period of time or based on certain events).

Say for two dateTime values X and Y, I need extract all the rows from the table where the date value is between X and Y.
If *flag* value is 1 or 2 then date_1 must be between X & Y irrespective of date_2. But if flag value is 3 then date_2 must be between X & Y irrespective of date_1.

For this I created three different queries with different parameters as flag=1/flag=2/flag=3. But this seems to be very inefficient.

```
String sql1 = "SELECT new xxxx.xxxx.xxx.Java.class.xxx ("
             + "t.flag, t.date_1, t.date_2)"
             + "FROM Table t "
             + "WHERE t.flag = :flagValue1 "
             + "AND t.date_1 >= :X "
             + "AND t.date_1 < :Y ";
String sql2 = "SELECT new xxxx.xxxx.xxx.Java.class.xxx ("
             + "t.flag, t.date_1, t.date_2)"
             + "FROM Table t "
             + "WHERE t.flag = :flagValue2 "
             + "AND t.date_1 >= :X "
             + "AND t.date_1 < :Y ";
String sql3 = "SELECT new xxxx.xxxx.xxx.Java.class.xxx ("
             + "t.flag, t.date_1, t.date_2)"
             + "FROM Table t "
             + "WHERE t.flag = :flagValue3 "
             + "AND t.date_2 >= :X "
             + "AND t.date_2 < :Y ";
List<E> list1 = this.entityManger.createQuery(sql1, model.class)
                 .setParameter("1", flag1)
                 .setParameter("X", firstDateValue)
                 .setParameter("Y", secondDateValue)
                 .getResultList();
List<E> list2 = this.entityManger.createQuery(sql2, model.class)
                 .setParameter("2", flag2)
                 .setParameter("X", firstDateValue)
                 .setParameter("Y", secondDateValue)
                 .getResultList();
List<E> list3 = this.entityManger.createQuery(sql3, model.class)
                 .setParameter("3", flag3)
                 .setParameter("X", firstDateValue)
                 .setParameter("Y", secondDateValue)
                 .getResultList();
List<E> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
        finalList.addAll(list1);
        finalList.addAll(list2);
        finalList.addAll(list3);
return finalList;
```

Is there any other way of doing this? What could be better (single)query for this ?

PS: I wonder if I can use Java 8's Lambda Functions for just filtering the values from the List. Any suggestions regarding this ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How about `t.flag IN ( :flagValue1, :flagValue2 , :flagValue3)`

Comment: how big datasets are we talking here? thousands, millions?

Comment: or make use of "OR" in the WHERE clause then there is 1 query. FWIW this is NOT SQL, so labelling your variables as "sqlX" is utterly misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand it correctly you actually have 2 input parameters X & Y (aka from/to Date). And you always want to query the values of all flags regarding the entered date. Therefore a query like this would be more efficient:

```
select new Java.class.name (t.flag, t.date_1, t.date_2) from Table t
where
(t.flag in (1,2) and t.date_1 >= :X and t.date_1 < :Y)
or 
(t.flag = 3 and  t.date_1 2= :X and t.date_2 < :Y)
```

This would reduce the whole thing to just one query ... may still be inefficient depending on the dataset.